# ErrorException in helpers.php line 454: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: arrays, string, validation, html-entities, laravel-5.1

I'm using simple html input as
`<input type="text" name="myName[]" />`

if i use laravel 5 validation on any of the form elements then it genereates an error as below
`ErrorException in helpers.php line 454: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

and if i remove the square brackets from myName input field then only the validation works.

I went through some of the answers over the web but none of them are solving the issue

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Because you have to loop each array input value. Eric Barnes has an answer of your question here : http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/

Comment: Your code does not generate the error. Can you show us more code of the view? Also check `@lang` parameter, when you pass an array instead of string this error is displayed

Comment: I have gone through https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2243 and http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/ but my problem differs as i can't use php loop because the input elements of the same type and name are added by js as per user requirements.

Comment: you definitely CAN loop beacause even with dynamic addition with js of input fields of same type your final result will always be an array like $_POST['your_input'][] and that's exactly what your error output is telling you.